# Is it possible to change schema type of particular field using mongoose pre hook

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongoose-schema

```
fR: {
        type: String,
        initial: true,
    }
```

The above schema will store values as string in db. But I want to store true & false values as Boolean in db. Is it possible to do that using pre hooks?

I am trying to change type of that field using hooks but failing to do so.

```
fR.schema.pre('save', function (next) {

    this.fR.map((obj) => {
        if (obj.value =='true') {
            obj.value= !!obj.value;
        }
         if( obj.value == 'true'){
            obj.type='Boolean'; //obj.type=Boolean
    
            obj.value = Boolean(obj.value);
         }
         if(obj.value == 'false'){
            obj.value = 0;
        }
        
    });
```